# Classes and Databases

Tags: php, oop

I have a class, called `Core()` That pretty much runs the management of my website.  It handles the routing, the header, body, footer etc and all files/database/authentication (login/logout) access.

So far it works great.  Pretty much All I have to do in my `index.php` is the following:

```
$core = new Core();
$core->render();
```

And the correct page will be rendered.

My problem is when it comes to databases.  I currently have my PDO database classes used by `Core()` as a trait, loaded from a separate file.

So in `Core::__construct` I have to manually start (what would be) the `__construct` function for the database:

`$this->database_initialize();`

Which connects to the database using the given credentials.

The problem I have is that sometimes I need to use other classes, and they also need access to the database.  Right now, if I need to run a select statement on one of the pages of the website I simply do the following:

`$this->select("SELECT foo FROM bar;");`

This is nice and easy, and part of my reasoning for using the `Database();` as a `trait` - Otherwise I would have to write `$this->db->select("SELECT`foo`FROM`bar`");` and I don't like typing out silly variables all the time. (Before I moved over to the whole OOP system, I was just typing `$table = select("");` which was nice and quick.)

So let's say I want to load a class on one of my pages, I would do the following:

`$form = New Form();`

That's fine, but how do I get that class to access the `$core` database that's already been loaded? Because inside the class `Form` I cannot write:

`$data = $this->select("");`

Because the class `Form` doesn't have a `select()` function.  Within the `Form` class, I also tried `$data = $core->select("")` but it has no idea who or what `$core` is either.

Little help?

Comment: Have you got a singleton pattern in the database?

Comment: You are not doing OOP. You just wrap everything in a class which is class oriented programming at best

Comment: @PeeHaa How can I improve it then to be OOP?

Comment: Protip: don't be afraid to type 4 more characters. Terseness often comes at the cost of flexibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters having a class called `Core` is a huge code smell. Which is also made clear by your next sentence:

> That pretty much runs the management of my website. It handles the routing, the header, body, footer etc and all files/database/authentication (login/logout) access.

This means you basically have a single class which is responsible everything and then some. Which means you gain nothing by wrapping it in a class.

> My problem is when it comes to databases. I currently have my PDO database classes used by Core() as a trait, loaded from a separate file.

What's the reason for using a trait (for this)?

> Otherwise I would have to write $this->db->select("SELECT foo FROM bar"); and I don't like typing out silly variables all the time

That's quite frankly the silliest thing I have heard today and a terrible reason to go one route or another.

If something needs a database connection pass it in:

```
$dbConnection         = new \PDO('{dsn}', 'user', 'pass');
$somethingThatNeedsDb = new SomethingThatNeedsDb($dbConnection);
```

> That's fine, but how do I get that class to access the $core database that's already been loaded?

You don't. You pass it also in the form that needs it:

```
$dbConnection         = new \PDO('{dsn}', 'user', 'pass');
$theForm              = new Form($dbConnection);
$somethingThatNeedsDb = new SomethingThatNeedsDb($dbConnection);
```

Comment: +1 for `quite frankly the silliest thing I have heard today`! And thank you for your input.  So are you saying then It would make more sense to lose the `Core()` class and have the website done procedurally?

Comment: "It would make more sense to lose the Core()". Yeah I think so it would be better to have classes with very specific responsibilities. E.g. a routing class, template rendering class, authentication class etc. And you can define them at bootstrap phase either in a [normal php file](https://github.com/CodeCollab/Demo/blob/master/bootstrap.php) to wire everything together or a bootstrap class which wires everything together.

Comment: Some [reading material](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html) and some [watching material](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLM-218uGSX3CUHPJqlTH0p2kcUZ1swFf0) for when you get bored :-)

Comment: So I've rewritten my entire site structure now to be non OOP, with the objects being things like `Database`, and now the code is much easier to maintain.  Thank you for you're help, My code is a lot more efficient now :)